# Restrict user actions with zend pdf

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Is it possible at all in Zend Framework (any version) to restrict user actions with Zend Pdf?

For example with Adobe Acrobat you can put a password on the PDF file and customize it by setting permissions on it. Such as allowed to copy, edit and print with valid password. Otherwise the user can, for example, only view the pdf.

I generate pdf files for the clients based on their profiles with zend pdf from Zend Framework 2. Some clients want the pdf to have by default only view permission. Is this possible through Zend Framework?

If it isn't, would using chmod be a good option to change the file permissions?

As a sidenote, yes I am fully aware that there are plenty of work-arounds in order to gain full access to the pdf, but having the view only permission filters out 99% of the users that would want to modify it.

If this is simply impossible, no matter how you look at it, is there any suggestion then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use all the pdf customizations you have to use external PDF libraries as Zend PDF doesn't provide all the customizations properly. I already have faced a lot of issues using Zend PDF and now I'm using MPDF which is very simple to use as compared to Zend PDF and also you can do all the stuffs that you want to do right now such as allowed to copy, edit and print with valid password etc. So go through this link you can find everything.

https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html.

Thanks.

Comment: This is quite a solid library, provides plenty of things as well for which I had written small helpers. If anything I'd call this pretty much complete with things you can do with pdf files.